# How to deploy ASP.Net MVC 5 to IIS 8 running Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis8

I developed an application in ASP.Net MVC 5 with database SQL Server 2012 now I want to deploy it in Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8

I followed this link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

but when I run my application in browser it gives error:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page can not be access because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

I am new in this area please if you could explain in details.

Answer (score 1):

That error usually contains more details about what about the configuration is wrong.  Are you attempting to load the we site from the server machine? (By default error message details are blocked except on the local machine).  Every time I've seen this error, it's been an xml formatting issue, an invalid element issue (unregistered custom config stuff) or a section locking issue.  Please get the details from the local machine.  If the solution isn't obvious after getting that information, update your question with that information.